# Getting tx_not_supported on steller-core prod v1.15.0

Tags: stellar-core

I am getting tx_not_supported when submitting a transaction.

I have compiled at stellar-core prod branch and launched a network. I am able to use the horizon and see the root account. However when trying a transaction/create account. I am getting tx_not_supported as an error in the transaction envelope.

Do I need to initiate the network to start accepting transactions or what else can be done?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add more information? Which SDK (and version) are you using? Which version of the protocol are you using (typically you need latest SDK against later version of the protocol)?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, which seems to be related to the fact that the submitted transaction is incompatible with the deployed version of your ledger. You can try to [upgrade the network](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/run-core-node/network-upgrades/) to the latest protocol version with the following command:

```
stellar-core http-command 'upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=2018-01-31T20:00:00Z&protocolversion=15'
```